# Django logout function is not working

Tags: python, django

I'm using the Django login and logout functions, the login function works, but the logout is not working.

In my HTML file, I have:

```
<a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}">logout</a>
<a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">login</a>
```

in my urls.py file I have:

```
url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {
    'template_name': 'blog/login.html'
    }),

url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {
    'template_name': 'blog/logout.html'
    }),
```

When I login, it works perfectly fine, and I can display the logged in person's name. But when I logout, I'm still logged in because the logged in user's name is still displayed in the banner area.

in my HTML file I have:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ user }}
{% endif %}
```

If the logout function worked, the user name shouldn't be displayed. So I'm assuming it is not working.

What seems to be the issue, any help/direction would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

Firstly, you have exactly the same URL pattern (`'^$'`) for both login and logout views. This means that the second (logout) pattern will never actually be used because the first one always matches. When you try to log out, the first view that matches is the login view, hence you can never log out.

Change it to:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {
    'template_name': 'blog/login.html'
}, name='login'),

url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {
    'template_name': 'blog/logout.html'
}, name='logout'),
```

(See the [documentation on using the authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views).)

Then in your template, you need to refer to the URLs using their names (which I have added above):

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
```

Your current approach (of passing a dotted path to a URL function) has been [deprecated since Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8/#passing-a-string-as-view-to-url) and was removed in Django 1.10, so you should stop using it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, you are right about the url pattern. And i will refrain from using the dotted approach :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  Hello {{ request.user.username }}.
{% else %}
  Hello Guest
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Does Django default logout function destroys the session? I'm assuming the problem lies there rather than the if statement. Also I have another if statement that checks if user is anonymous, if so then some menus shouldn't appear, yet when I logout, those menus still appear.

Comment: Yes, Django default logout function destroys the session. I was trying to say, you have check user authentication with request, like this `request.user.is_authenticated `.

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure that your app settings comes first before Django default apps in your settings.py file under INSTALLED_APPS else your logout template wouldn’t be rendered and Django default logout page would be displayed instead.